# Show that for a symmetric matrix $L_h$, $\|v_i\|_2 \leq C\|L_hv_i\|_2$ for some constant $C$

Tags: linear-algebra

say I have some symmetric matrix $L_h$. I know i can decompose it into

$L_h = Q\Lambda Q^T$ for diagonal matrix $\Lambda$ of eigenvalues and orthogonal matrices $Q,Q^T$ of eigenvectors.

Then,
\begin{align}
\|L_hv_i\|_2^2 Y & = \langle L_hv_i,L_hv_i\rangle \\[10pt]
& = \langle Q\Lambda Q^Tv_i, Q\Lambda Q^Tv_i\rangle \\[10pt]
& = (Q\Lambda Q^Tv_i)^T(Q\Lambda Q^Tv_i) \\[10pt]
& = v_i^TQ\Lambda Q^TQ\Lambda Q^Tv_i \\[10pt]
& = v_i^TQ\Lambda^2Q^Tv_i
\end{align}

but I'm not sure I can derive more from here. I know the eigenvalues and eigenvectors for this matrix, as they are those of the 2D discrete LaPlacian, but can I say any more without this knowledge?

Comment: Is $L_h$ invertible?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $L_h$ is invertible (otherwise the statement is false), we have
that 
\begin{align}
v_i^TQ\Lambda^2 Q^Tv_i  = w_i^T\Lambda^2 w_i \geq \min (|\lambda|^2) \|w_i\|^2 = \min (|\lambda|^2) \|Q^Tv_i\|^2 = \min (|\lambda|^2) \|v_i\|^2. 
\end{align}